# GravityView Ajax Link

Tags: ajax, wordpress, gravityforms

I have a table created with GravityView and I want to implement the single entry link with Ajax so that the page does not refresh and the URL does not change.
Is such a thing possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V69Yu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using GravityView! Zack here, founder.

We’re going to be adding this functionality later this year. If you wait a few months, it’ll be ready!

Answer (score 1):

You can load the single entry page with jQuery .load method.

You would need to pass the URL of the page, in this case I am trying to get the content on another page whose URL is in the anchor link of the table, in your case its link field.

So i give the .load method URL + the id of the accordion in which the content i need to display exists, and a call back function.

Here how I did it.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  // select the div where you want to display content
  var $loadedContent = $('#fl-accordion-5c450fd66133e-panel-0');
  // register an event, get the click event of the link
  $(document).on('click','.gv-field-3-date_created a', function(event) {
      //stop the link form opening
      event.preventDefault();
      //get URL from the href attribute of the anchor link
      var $url = $(this).attr("href");
      // send the request and get the response, In my case I am trying to show the content inside a accordian, so i have taken its ID and added that with URL
      $loadedContent.load($url+' #fl-accordion-5c450fd66133e-panel-0', completeFunction);
      return false;
  });

  function completeFunction(responseText, textStatus, request) {
      if(textStatus == 'error') {
          // show a relevant message
          $loadedContent.text('An error occurred during your request: ' +  request.status + ' ' + request.statusText);
      } 
  }
  });
```

Just add your classes, and it will get the Job Done.